# CakePHP 2.4.1 and PHP 5.5.9 issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application works fine with PHP: 5.3.8. However, it generates the following error with PHP: 5.5.9

```
Non-static method AppHelper::isCurrent() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

in `View/Themed/Slate/Helper/AppHelper.php` I have made this code:

```
function isCurrent($txt, $className = 'active'){                                               
                if ($txt == strtolower($this->name.$this->action)){
                            return $className;
                   }
                   else{
                            return '';
                   }
}
```

In the past, before upgrade the PHP, I used to call this function from the view as follows:

```
<?php echo AppHelper::isCurrent('contactsindex', 'active'); ?>
```

I tried to prefix the function name with `public static` to void this error but it failed to solve this issue. I need to know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Static functions do not have `$this` by definition. Perhaps previous PHP versions didn't warn you about the error (:-?) but it couldn't possibly work. You have to do what PHP asks you to (please read the error carefully).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario When I use `$this->isCurrent()` it generates a fetal error of calling undefined function in View!

Comment: is isCurrent() method in your view?

Comment: In addition: `AppHelper::, AppModel::, AppController::` they are the way that I know to use a method defined in each of them in any view, model, controller respectively.

Comment: @IsaacRajaei No it is defined in AppHelper as I regarded above.

Comment: set your method public lets see if it works. then call it with $this->Html->isCurr.. from your view

Comment: I'm not very proficient with CakePHP but you don't seem to be using the [syntax explained in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#using-helpers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tr this

//View/Helper/AppHelper

```
class AppHelper extends Helper {

        public function isCurrent($txt, $className = 'active'){                                               
                    if ($txt == strtolower($this->name.$this->action)){
                                return $className;
                       }
                       else{
                                return '';
                       }
        }

    }
```

//View

```
<?php echo $this->Html->isCurrent('contactsindex', 'active'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine. However, it did not need to add public keyword.

Comment: @sємsєм - Omitting the `public` keyword doesn't change anything because that's the default visibility.